# How to daisy chain displays from HDMI to DP?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

If I have a laptop (one is a few years old, the other is brand new), with thunderbolt port... how do I hang two displays from the one thunderbolt port?

Currently, I use a USB-C to HDMI adapter, which works fine for driving one display.

Can I daisy a second display off the first, via hdmi or DP?

I notice that newer displays have single HDMI port, and both DP-in and DP-out. How would I go from my laptops to that kind of setup?

Thanks!

**IMPLEMENTED SOLUTION**

A high end docking station that connects to thunderbolt and provides multiple HDMI and/or DP ports. Hang the displays off the dock. Life is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite clear what your setup is (e.g., What laptop are you using? What displays do you have (and what ports do they have)?). Normally, I'd comment your question to provide more details, but I do not have comment privileges yet. Instead, I'll try to provide a general answer.

HDMI doesn't permit daisy chaining, only DP does. I believe this means that you can only daisychain using DP (including a thunderbolt -> DP adapter). You won't be able to connect to monitor 1 using DP and then connect monitor 1 to monitor 2 using HDMI. Thus, your current adapter (usb-c -> HDMI) is probably not suitable for your goal.

You do have a few options. You might be able to use a thunderbolt -> DP adapter to connect to monitor 1's input and then connect monitor 1's output to monitor 2's input using a male-male displayport cable. Note that [not all laptops support this](https://medium.com/@sebvance/everything-you-need-to-know-about-macbook-pros-and-their-lack-of-displayport-mst-multi-stream-98ce33d64af4).

If your monitors have usb-c ports, you may be able to [daisy chain using usb-c directly, without the need of adapters](https://insights.samsung.com/2020/04/13/connecting-monitors-with-usb-c-and-daisy-chaining/).

Lastly, you can use a usb-c dock that have 2 video output ports (HDMI or DP or whatever). I have a Lenovo L380 and a [Lenovo non-thunderbolt usb-c dock](https://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/accessories/acc100348). I am able to drive 2 displayport monitors in addition to my laptop's display. I plug the dock's outputs directly to the monitor's inputs.

If you choose to use daisychaining, be sure to ensure that your laptop and monitors support it. On monitors, this means each monitor will have DP input and output ports. You'll also want to google your laptop (or see its manual) to ensure it allows daisychaining through thunderbolt.

You'll also want to ensure that your laptop's GPU can support 2 displays (or 3 if you also want to use your laptop's screen). Since your laptop is new, it probably should, but it doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: Thanks!  After digging far and wide, I am going with the USB-C dock with multiple monitor ports (dual HDMI in my case).  I am starting to see the issue with 4K monitors, that it is a bandwidth limitation (It appears impossible to daisy chain 4K displays on DP in general...).

Comment: It is possible, but most implementations have limited bandwidth. So with most laptops you have the choice between single 4k (60Hz) or dual 4k (30 or 24Hz).  Works if you want a bill board, but anoying for just about everything else. So either a dock or multiple output on the laptop is the way to go.